# css: How do I make the child of %-defined height div scrollable with a visible height equal to the parent?

Tags: css

I have a modal with display content be set at `70%` of the window height.

Attached codepen here: [Link](https://codepen.io/rylangrady/pen/eYpmeaN)

I want to have a portion of that modal content have a `overflow-y: scroll`, and I want the visible area within that scrollable section to always be 100% of the parent.

When I try to set the height of the scrollable section to `100%`, it grows so large that it no longer scrolls, and extends the height beyond the overflow hidden of the parent element.  If I set it to a fixed height in pixels, when I zoom in or out in my browser, there are conditions where the left div does not cover the full height of its parent.

How can I achieve a behavior such that, no matter how far in or out the user zooms with a mouse, the light green div on the left is always the full height of the modal (`70%`) and has a scroll bar to allow viewing of overflow when the content extends beyond the parent modal's height?

Comment: can you define visible area? do you mean the division or the progress bars? Do you want them to be a dynamic size relative to the zoom which makes them look static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have understood your question right you want:

1. Ability to scroll
2. Have a fixed height similar to parent

If that is correct you are able to do so by using VH as a measurment. VH represents the viewport whilst % represents the parent. if the body is 500vh and the division has a height of 100%, that division will have the same height as 5 pages.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffee;
  padding:0px;
}

.modal {
  position:fixed;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width:100%;
  height:100%
}
.modal-header, .modal-footer {
  background-color:rgb(255,220,190)
}

.modal-footer {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%
}

.modal-content {
  height:70vh;
  background-color:white;
  position:relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.modal-grid-container {
  background-color:rgb(200,255,200);
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 35fr 65fr;

}

.modal-grid-right {
  height:inherit;
}

.modal-grid-left{
  height: 70vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.modal-grid-right{
  background-color:rgb(230,230,255);
}

.progress-bar {
  width:20px;
  height:15vh;
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">


<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      Header Text
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modal-grid-container">
        <div class="modal-grid-left">
          <p>Here's a progress bar</p>
          <div class="progress-bar"></div>
          <div class="progress-bar"></div>
          <div class="progress-bar"></div>
          <div class="progress-bar"></div>
          <div class="progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-grid-right">
          <h2> Question: How can I make the visible area in the left section always be the same height as the parent div, regardless of the user zooming in or out significantly?</h2>
          <p>Lots of content here</p>
          <p>Lots of content here</p>
          <p>Lots of content here</p>
          <p>Lots of content here</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      Footer text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>This is some web content!</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation!  Exactly what I needed.